# Android Download Manager says cannot open file after downloading

Tags: android

i am using Android built-in Download Manager to download a video file and i am using following code to do it:

```
 DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                                              downloadUri);

                                      request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(
                                              DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI
                                                      | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)

                                              .setAllowedOverRoaming(true)
                                              .setDescription("mohammediatechnologies.in")
                                              .setNotificationVisibility(request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
                                              .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/videodownloader", title+quality);
                                  long id = mgr.enqueue(request);
```

In this i am passing a url to download a video. every thing is fine it downloads the file and stores it to download folder but. when i click on notification after finishing downloading it says cannt open file please let me know where i am doing wrong. I have checked with extensions and all.

Comment: is the size of video downloaded same as original?

Comment: yes i have checked several times . with several formats of videos and still getting it

Comment: just a suggest try to set specific values like setMimeType or downloadfiletype and accordingly try download that particular format...accrodinlg u can customize the stuff

Comment: Make sure you save the file with the correct file extension. If there is no app that can handle the file's mime-type this error will show.

Comment: i have checked the extension . file is downloaded to file manager i can acess the file from there

Answer (score 4):

Your supposed to set mimetype as pdf like so

```
 request.setMimeType("application/type of file");
```

within your download manager code