# After downloading video file with android download manager it's not work

Tags: java, android, android-download-manager

After downlaoding video file with android downlaod manager ,

> it say `Sorry cannot play this video

1. First of all I check size of the file and it's same with original
   file
2. for checking i install third party software like a `mxplayer` and
   again it's not work
3. it have a sound but it show nothing.
4. other extensions supported and opened with programs

This is My code : I use this in `onClickListener` of one Button in `RecyclerView`

```
 public void onClick(View v) {

                DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService (Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(questionha.get(position).getQuestionDownLink()));

                request.setTitle(questionha.get(position).getQuestionTitle())
                        .setDescription("downloading ...")
                        .setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context, "", questionha.get(position).getQuestionDownFileName());
                long enqueueId = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
            }
```

I found same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27269813/android-download-manager-says-cannot-open-file-after-downloading) here but it haven't answer ,And This is the Image of my files in EsFileExplorer

https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5BXG.jpg

I add my json response too :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGIUd.jpg

Comment: Have you verified the checksum of the video file, that is the same on both endpoints? Also, what kind of video file is it, if its windows video file, flv, ogg, chances are, that Android is not capable of playing it back due to lack of encoder/decoder on handset itself.

Comment: 1.what you mean from checksum 2.my file is .mov file

Comment: .mov file are windows media playback files.... as for checksum, there's MD5, SHA1 hash checksums, that enables you to verify that the download is not corrupted.

Comment: i check the mp4 file too but nothing . i think this problem should happen via add filename to the file . i get the file name with json and setting this json reesponse as file name (name + extensions). what you think am i right ?

Comment: wait, are you renaming the .mov to .mp4? That won't work either if that's the case. Show us the filename of the video clip on the server, also, show us the JSON response, BTW, there was no mention of JSON in the question!

Comment: no , i get other video file , not renaming .mov to mp4 .

Comment: i add the json response in the end of question

Comment: Please refrain from posting images of json responses or any kind of textual responses on this site. Now, why did you mention .mov files? Try setting the [Mime Type](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Request.html#setMimeType(java.lang.String)) to `application/octet-stream`

Comment: I add this line request.setMimeType("application/octet-stream");  but nothing

Comment: Update your code to reflect that. Maybe you need to add a header...